# Vert.x aerospike client to use context-bound event loop

Tags: performance, concurrency, vert.x, event-loop, aerospike

Standard [java aerospike client](https://developer.aerospike.com/client/java)'s methods have overloads allowing to provide [EventLoop](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-java/blob/master/client/src/com/aerospike/client/async/EventLoop.java) as an argument. When running in vert.x that client is not aware of context-bounded event loop and just fallbacks to `if (eventLoop == null) { eventLoop = cluster.eventLoops.next(); }` which could(and likely does) causes context switching/level of concurrency which in turn affects performance (it's still in theory, but I want to prove it), because there is no guarantee that aerospike requests will run on the same event loop as coming http request according to [Vert.x Multi Reactor](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_reactor_and_multi_reactor) pattern. Open source aerospike clients like [vertx-aerospike-client](https://github.com/dream11/vertx-aerospike-client) also have such a disadvantage. Using vert.x there is no way(at least I'm not aware of) to retrieve context-bounded event loop and pass it to aerospike client.

Vert.x has method to retrieve Context [Vertx.currentContext()](https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/blob/2439c849549b08a1e7ffee8f09eae886c9fe88f6/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/Vertx.java#L116) but retrieving EventLoop is not available.

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems some feedback on this question here: https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/vert-x-aerospike-client-to-use-context-bound-event-loop/9704

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've built this:

```
public class ContextEventLoop {
    private final NettyEventLoops eventLoops;

    public ContextEventLoop(final NettyEventLoops eventLoops) {
        this.eventLoops = Objects.requireNonNull(eventLoops, "eventLoops");
    }

    public EventLoop resolve() {
        final ContextInternal ctx = ContextInternal.current();
        final EventLoop eventLoop;
        if (ctx != null
                && ctx.isEventLoopContext()
                && (eventLoop = eventLoops.get(ctx.nettyEventLoop())) != null) {
            return eventLoop;
        }
        return eventLoops.next();
    }
}

@NotNull
public EventLoops wrap(final EventLoops fallback,
                       final Supplier<@NotNull EventLoop> next) {
    return new EventLoops() {
        @Override
        public EventLoop[] getArray() {
            return fallback.getArray();
        }

        @Override
        public int getSize() {
            return fallback.getSize();
        }

        @Override
        public EventLoop get(int index) {
            return fallback.get(index);
        }

        @Override
        public EventLoop next() {
            return next.get();
        }

        @Override
        public void close() {
            fallback.close();
        }
    };
}
```